# Python Multithreaded HTTP crawler - Closing connection and hanging of the program

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2

Wrote this crawler in Python, it dumps several parameters to JSON output file based on the input list of domains.

Have this question:

Do I need to close the HTTP connection in each thread?  Input data is ca. 5 Million items. It process at the beginning at a rate ca. 50 iterations per second, but later after some time it drops to 1-2 per second and/or hangs (no kernel messages and no errors on stdout)? Can this be code or is network limiting related? I suspect software since when I restart it, it starts again with high rate (ca. 50 iteration per second)

Any tips how to improve the code below are also welcome, especially improve on speed and crawling throughput.

Code in questions:

```
import urllib2
import pprint
from tqdm import tqdm

import lxml.html

from Queue import Queue

from geoip import geolite2
import pycountry

from tld import get_tld



resfile = open("out.txt",'a')



concurrent = 200

def doWork():
    while True:
        url = q.get()
        status = getStatus(url)
        doSomethingWithResult(status)
        q.task_done()

def getStatus(ourl):
     try:
       response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+ourl)
       peer = response.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()
       ip = peer[0]
       header = response.info()
       html = response.read()
       html_element = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
       generator = html_element.xpath("//meta[@name='generator']/@content")
       try:
         match = geolite2.lookup(ip)
         if match is not None:
           country= match.country
           try:

             c=pycountry.countries.lookup(country)
             country=c.name
           except:
             country=""

       except:
         country=""
       try:
         res=get_tld("http://www"+ourl, as_object=True)
         tld=res.suffix
       except:
         tld=""

       try:
         match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', html)
         email=match.group(0)
       except:
         email=""

       try:
           item= generator[0]
           val = "{ \"Domain\":\"http://"+ourl.rstrip()+"\",\"IP:\""+ip+"\"," + "\"Server\":"+ "\""+str(header.getheader("Server")).replace("None","")+"\",\"PoweredBy\":" + "\""+str(header.getheader("X-Powered-By")).replace("None","")+"\""+",\"MetaGenerator\":\""+item+"\",\"Email\":\""+email+"\",\"Suffix\":\""+tld+"\",\"CountryHosted\":\""+country+"\" }"
       except:
           val = "{ \"Domain\":\"http://"+ourl.rstrip()+"\",\"IP:\""+ip+"\"," + "\"Server\":"+ "\""+str(header.getheader("Server")).replace("None","")+"\",\"PoweredBy\":" + "\""+str(header.getheader("X-Powered-By")).replace("None","")+"\""+",\"MetaGenerator\":\"\",\"Email\":\""+email+"\",\"Suffix\":\""+tld+"\",\"CountryHosted\":\""+country+"\" }"

       return val
     except Exception as e:
       #print "error"+str(e)
       pass

def doSomethingWithResult(status):
    if status:
      resfile.write(str(status)+"\n")

q = Queue(concurrent * 2)
for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=doWork)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

try:
    for url in tqdm(open('list.txt')):
        q.put(url.strip())
        status = open("status.txt",'w')
        status.write(str(url.strip()))   
    q.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Update 1:

Closing the Socket and FileDescriptor makes it work better, does not seem to hang anymore after some time. Performance is 50 reqs/sec on home laptop and ca 100 req/sec on a VPS

```
from threading import Thread
import httplib, sys
import urllib2
import pprint
from tqdm import tqdm

import lxml.html

from Queue import Queue

from geoip import geolite2
import pycountry

from tld import get_tld
import json



resfile = open("out.txt",'a')



concurrent = 200

def doWork():
    while True:
        url = q.get()
        status = getStatus(url)
        doSomethingWithResult(status)
        q.task_done()

def getStatus(ourl):
     try:
       response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+ourl)
       realsock = response.fp._sock.fp._sock
       peer = response.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()
       ip = peer[0]
       header = response.info()
       html = response.read()
       realsock.close()
       response.close()

       html_element = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
       generator = html_element.xpath("//meta[@name='generator']/@content")
       try:
         match = geolite2.lookup(ip)
         if match is not None:
           country= match.country
           try:

             c=pycountry.countries.lookup(country)
             country=c.name
           except:
             country=""

       except:
         country=""
       try:
         res=get_tld("http://www"+ourl, as_object=True)
         tld=res.suffix
       except:
         tld=""

       try:
         match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', html)
         email=match.group(0)
       except:
         email=""

       try:
           item= generator[0]
           val = "{ \"Domain\":"+json.dumps("http://"+ourl.rstrip())+",\"IP\":\""+ip+"\",\"Server\":"+json.dumps(str(header.getheader("Server")).replace("None",""))+",\"PoweredBy\":" +json.dumps(str(header.getheader("X-Powered-By")).replace("None",""))+",\"MetaGenerator\":"+json.dumps(item)+",\"Email\":"+json.dumps(email)+",\"Suffix\":\""+tld+"\",\"CountryHosted\":\""+country+"\" }"
       except:
           val = "{ \"Domain\":"+json.dumps("http://"+ourl.rstrip())+",\"IP\":\""+ip+"\"," + "\"Server\":"+json.dumps(str(header.getheader("Server")).replace("None",""))+",\"PoweredBy\":" +json.dumps(str(header.getheader("X-Powered-By")).replace("None",""))+",\"MetaGenerator\":\"\",\"Email\":"+json.dumps(email)+",\"Suffix\":\""+tld+"\",\"CountryHosted\":\""+country+"\" }"

       return val
     except Exception as e:
       print "error"+str(e)
       pass

def doSomethingWithResult(status):
    if status:
      resfile.write(str(status)+"\n")

q = Queue(concurrent * 2)
for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=doWork)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

try:
    for url in tqdm(open('list.txt')):
        q.put(url.strip())
        status = open("status.txt",'w')
        status.write(str(url.strip()))   
    q.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handles will be automatically garbage collected, but, you will be better off closing the handles yourself, especially as you are doing this in a tight loop.

You also asked for suggestions for improvement. A big one would be to stop using `urllib2` and start using `requests` instead.

Comment: THANKS!!!! I close the socket and than descriptor and it works better now. Will look into requests ....

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible options, why your crawling rate drops.

1.) Take care not to crawl to much data from the same domain. Some web servers are configured just to allow one connection per IP address in parallel.

2.) Try to send randomized browser-like http headers (user-agent, referrer, ...) to prevent web server scraping protection, if set.

3.) Use a mature http (parallel) library, like pycurl (has [MultiCurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlmultiobject.html)) or requests ([grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)). They perform faster for sure.

Comment: Thanks!!! I have chosen other answer since it was more directed at my question. I wish I could choose two answers, since your is also very good.